# Rails environment variable relative or absolute path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants, environment, pathname

Using rails 4, I need to generate an environment variable from a relative url in development, and an absolute-one in production

DEV :
    SOME_PATH = [Rails root]/some_path

PROD :
    SOME_PATH = [Some absolute path]/some_other_path

I'm storing these variables in a yml file, following the instructions I found [there](http://richonrails.com/articles/environment-variables-in-ruby-on-rails).
What would be a nice way/best practice to store and generate these variables ?

For example, in my yml I could write:

```
development:
  DOCETUDE_PATH: some_path
production:
  DOCETUDE_PATH: /home/public/some_other_path
```

And somewhere in my code I must generate the Pathname variables. This seems to work but looks hackish:

```
if (ENV['DOCETUDE_PATH'].start_with?("/"))
    MY_CST = Pathname.new(ENV['DOCETUDE_PATH']
else 
    MY_CST = File.join(Rails.root, ENV['DOCETUDE_PATH'])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are your requirements, those are your requirements.

I might base it on the Rails environment rather than the path name, in case of fat-fingering, or include a check of path v. environment to make sure nobody fat-fingers the configuration.

I might use a Ruby environment init file instead of the environment, too, so it's all code.

If I was doing it your way I'd refactor some of the code so it looked more like:

```
path = ENV['DOCETUDE_PATH']
MY_CST = relative_path?(path) ? Pathname.new(path) : File.join(Rails.root, path)
```

*(And create the `relative_path?` method, of course, if it doesn't already exist somewhere.)*